# How to layer D3 Force Simulation nodes based on element and not node order?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a a D3 v4 force simulation with nodes moving around the screen. Each node is a group consisting of a circle and some text below it. How do I order this so that the circles are on a bottom layer and the text on a top layer always. It's okay for a circle to overlap a circle, but it's never okay for a circle to overlap on top of text. Here is what I've got. Currently, the node's circle that is ahead of the other node will overlap that node's text.

```
  this.centerNode = this.d3Graph.selectAll(null)
          .data(this.nodes.slice(10,20))
          .enter()
          .append("g")

          this.centerNode.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "backCircle")
            .attr("r", 60)
            .attr("fill", "red")


            this.centerNode
            .append("text")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("font-size", "20px")
            .attr("y", -60)
            .text("test text" )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot achieve the desired outcome with your current approach. The reason is simple: each group has a text and a circle. However, the painting order depends on the order of the groups:

```html
<g>
  <circle></circle>
  <text></text><!-- this text here... -->
</g>
<g>
  <circle></circle><!-- ...will be behind this circle here -->
  <text></text>
</g>
<!-- etc... -->
```

So, grouping the texts and the circles inside `<g>` elements, you will have the groups painted in a given order and, consequently, a circle over a text (the circle of a given group is painted over the texts of all groups before it).

Here is a demo (the `Baz` circle will be on top of all texts, and the `Bar` circle will be on top of `Foo` text):

```js
var width = 300;
var height = 200;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = [{
  name: "Foo"
}, {
  name: "Bar"
}, {
  name: "Baz"
}];

var links = [{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 1
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 2
}];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var link = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("stroke-width", 1);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var node = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));

var nodeCircle = node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("stroke", "gray")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  });

var nodeTexts = node.append("text")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("dx", 20)
  .attr("dy", 8)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

simulation.nodes(nodes);
simulation.force("link")
  .links(links);

simulation.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })

  node.attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")

});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

#### Solution

A possible solution is creating two selections, one for the circles and one for the texts. Append the circles **before**, and the texts **later**. Remember to use the same `nodes` array for both:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  //etc...

var nodeTexts = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  //etc...
```

That way, the texts will be **always** on top of the circles.

Check the demo:

```js
var width = 300;
var height = 200;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = [{
  name: "Foo"
}, {
  name: "Bar"
}, {
  name: "Baz"
}];

var links = [{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 1
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 2
}];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var link = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("stroke-width", 1);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var node = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("stroke", "gray")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));

var nodeTexts = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("dx", 20)
  .attr("dy", 8)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

simulation.nodes(nodes);
simulation.force("link")
  .links(links);

simulation.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })

  node.attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")

  nodeTexts.attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```