# How to add and remove nodes with nested groups inside a D3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 force layout that updates the number of nodes several times per second and that is called by restartD3(). I currently have a circle appended to each node and that works great. However, I now need to have 2 circles per node, but the key here is that they need to be on unique layers by type not by node, so I need to put them in groups. Here is the grouping layering that I am talking about: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492323/how-to-layer-d3-force-simulation-nodes-based-on-element-and-not-node-order)

I want this.circleNode to become an outer group for 2 other groups inside so that I only have to manipulate x and y position for the outer group and the 2 inner groups move as well. Here is my current code with just 1 outer group for the nodes but no groups nested inside yet:

```
// Create force simulation
this.force = d3.forceSimulation(this.users)
.alphaDecay(0)
.velocityDecay(0)
.on('tick', this.tickActions);


// Create circle nodes
this.circleNode = this.d3Graph.selectAll(null)
.enter()
.append("g")


// Call our restartD3 function
this.restartD3();

// My restartD3 function
restartD3() {

// Circles
this.circleNode = this.circleNode.data(this.users, function(d) {
  return d.id;
});

this.circleNode.exit().remove();

this.circleNode = this.circleNode
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "usercircles")
.attr("r", this.userRadius)
.attr("fill", d => "#00aced")
.merge(this.circleNode)

this.force.nodes(this.users);
}
```

I haven't been able to implement this, and my attempts have been far off with nothing rendering. Any guidance on nesting groups in a node that works with updating a lot would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal, concrete and verifiable example? It is unclear what your data structure is, and if there are other parts of the code that is problematic. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've created a test case using sample data, and it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/sjLsf0mm/30/